# Integrating Java App with HTML Page

Tags: java, html, web-services, file-io, integration

I have created a java app that will discover all the files in a folder and tell me which one is the newest.  How can I make a web page run the java app every 5 seconds or so and display a link to the newest file on the web page?

Thanks
David

Comment: Is the app running on your server?

Comment: What type of webserver are you running — Apache HTTPD, Apache Tomcat, GlassFish, Jetty, nginx, IIS, or maybe something else?

Comment: I think an applet is probably the way to go.  Is there an easy way to convert a java app to an applet?

Comment: And the app is running on my server, which I believe is Apache Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Java applet and integrate it to Html page .

Comment: Thanks, I have tried doing that but haven't had much success so far.  I more or less kept the program the same, but I just made the class extends Applet.  Then I just referenced the program from one of my web pages like <applet code='FirstApplet.class'> </applet>.  Is there anything else I should try to get it to run the program?  At the moment it doesn't do open any files or give any error messages.